# Programmatically Creating Constraints for a Programmatically made UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am Working on a UITextField that basically asks for the name of a new project... I want to set (programatically not storyboard style) contraints. I have had issues due to the fact that a UITextField made programmatically has to have some sort of frame... Which is why I am wondering how to set the contraints without conflicting with the parameters I had set using (frame: CGRect(x: floatValue , y: floatValue , width: floatvalue , height: floatValue ,)) as a param for UITextField... the floatValues are all actual float values like 10.0 and 100.0 etc, Which is why im having trouble setting constraints on something that already has a fixed X and Y and can be deleted without erroring CGRect... if anyone could point me in the right direction like using constraints as a param please let me know!!!

Comment: Could post your code and show what have you tried. Can't tell where you went wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: Welcome @PandaDev on StackOverflow, I would request you to attach your code snippet. It will help community member to understand your issue better and they can help you quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with constraints, you don't need to set a frame. Consider the following example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let textField = UITextField()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureTextField()
}

private func configureTextField() {
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1 // just to make it more visible on the screen
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(textField)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    ])
}
}
```

Comment: Yes that was what I was looking for... I am new to swift and the UIkit scene so thank you so much for the help!